# Android studio printing a line of text from the menu

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, textview

I can't seem to figure out a simple problem. I'm using Android Studio and all I am trying to achieve is selecting a menu item that will just add text below the hello world and it will print it as many times as you push the menu button. All my code does now is to replace a text view field that has an id with another string. I messed around with options like replacing the greetingview = (textview) findViewById to something that pulls the string but it all came up with errors.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView greetingView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    greetingView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newMessage);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_message){
        greetingView.setText(R.string.message);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is the blank text I replace with the message.

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/newMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/helloWorld"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the new text with the original value, followed by a new line character(\n).
Please also make sure the text view will have enough height to hold the newly appended text.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_message){
            greetingView.setText(greetingView.getText() + "\n" + R.string.message);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this when I have a chance.  In order to add text like that do you always need some sort of text field to place the text into?  I am just curious.

Comment: @NickInman First you have to decide why you need to add text. E.g., If your text field is a "log" which increases as the system outputs new messages, you can just append the new text after the original one (replace the new text with the original one, but still using the same text view control). If you are going to add new items which can be clicked, you should use a listview (or other container) to hold the text views and add a new text view everytime instead of replacing the original one.